Exercise on complex numbers (Ahlfors)
I am trying to do the following exercise on complex numbers without using the exponential representation of a complex number (Ahlfors puts this exercise before introducing this notation, so I think there is a possible way to solve it without using the exponential representation):
"if $\omega=\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}$, prove that $1+\omega^h+\omega^{2h}+....+\omega^{(n-1)h}=0$ for any integer $h$ which is not a multiple of $n$".
I tried to proceed in two different ways:
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\omega^{kh}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\cos\frac{2k}{n}+i\sin\frac{2k}{n}\right)^h=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}1^{\frac{h}{n}}=n$ because $\cos\frac{2k}{n}+i\sin\frac{2k}{n}$ is an $n$-th root of $1$ for all $k=0,...,n-1$.
Alternatively,
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\omega^{kh}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\cos\frac{2kh}{n}+i\sin\frac{2kh}{n}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\frac{2kh}{n}+i\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\frac{2kh}{n}$ and this is equal to $0$ if and only if $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\frac{2kh}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\frac{2kh}{n}=0$, but I do not know why this should be true....
What am I missing and what mistakes am I making?
Thanks for any answer and help!

Note that $\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n-1}(\omega^{h})^{k}$ is a geometric sum. Try applying the formula for that.

Right! And $\omega^k \neq 1 $ because $h$ is not a multiple of $n$. This is the key, right?

Yes, correct, $\omega^{h} \neq 1$.

Your first procedure is based on the idea that $\omega^k = 1^\frac 1n = 1$. Sorry, but unless $k$ is a multiple of $n$, $\omega^k$ and $1$ are different $n$-th roots of $1$.
